# Phonegap adding plugin using command line tool

Tags: git, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new in phonegap, i go through steps define in phonegap official site for creating project using command line tool(**nodejs**). i success to create project and adding platform but,

following error occur when i am trying to add plugin.

Command :

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-battery-status.git
```

error :

```
[Error: Error fetching plugin: Error: git command line is not installed]
```

how can i resolve this error and how can i install git command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The phonegap 3's new CLI is no longer cordova plugin add - It is ```phonegap local plugin add <path>``` See [add feature](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_add_features)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could install git command line for **Mac OS X** in [here](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.8.3.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg&can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded), and then try run that again.
**For Windows**, download Git on [code.google.com/p/msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/). 
Then: git clone git://project.url.here

Comment: Thanks @wesson. but i am using window system can it possible to install in window system and how? thanks in advance

Comment: for windows, Download Git on https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/. Then:

git clone git://project.url.here

Comment: No worries. Most important thing is you fixed your problem.

Comment: @ButaniVijay - can you type the correct command to install the git plugin for phonegap project. I am trying after install the git, but i cant install the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Error shown that you have not installed git command line tool. if you want to use git command first you need to install git command line tool. then you can add plugins ass per your requirements.

Comment: How is this accepted as a better answer than the one below? Supply sources next time, rather than repeating what the error said was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Site for git on Windows has moved to:
http://msysgit.github.io/