# Not able to add Plugin to phonegap Cordova 3.1.0

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to add plugin to cordova project  using the command

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

And am getting following error message

```
Fetching plugin from "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"...
[Error: Error fetching plugin: Error: error: Could not fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser]
```

An tried solution provided in following SO link :

[Phonegap adding plugin using command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849702/phonegap-adding-plugin-using-command-line-tool)

Still am getting same error

Comment: Do you have node.js installed? Can you build the project without errors?

Comment: yes i can able to build the project @VicM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add through following command.I have done that successfully

"cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git"(with no quotes).

And if you getting this error after installing git command line tool then you need to restart your MAC.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with my own plugins. Adding the package.json-file solved it for me.

Comment: Where should i add it and where can i get it ?

Comment: The file should be under plugins/yourPlugin. If you have other plugins installed you can copy and paste the package.json from there and then change it for your plugin. That's the way I did it.

Comment: I already have the package.json in such directory, but the problem is still present.